# Amazon AWS key pair is no longer safe to use. How do I disable/replace this key pair on an ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

If someone else has possession of our private key for an ec2 instance, and so the key pair is no longer safe to use, how should we proceed?

From what I understand, there is no way to replace the key pair once the instance has started running. The only option I think is to somehow replace the current ec2 instance with a new one (a copy, containing the exact same data/volume and hopefully with the same ip address), but I'm not sure how to do this safely (and preferably with minimal downtime of our servers). This way, a new key pair can be generated and the old one will become obsolete, once the old instance is terminated. Otherwise, another option may be to somehow disable the current key pair and add a new one, but I have no idea how to do that either (and it's probably not the best long term solution either).

Can someone provide me instructions for the best solution in this scenario? And hopefully let me know if I'm on the right track. Working with aws can be dangerous so I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relax. It is not very difficult and no need to terminate the instance. Always keep multiple sessions open before changing keypairs, so that if you make a mistake, you can use the other ssh sessions to restore the access.

In this example, I am assuming user as `ubuntu`, but applies to any user.

1. Take an AMI of the machine in case something goes wrong
2. Generate a new keypair. Keep the private key in a safe location. Let the public key be `key.pub`
3. Edit `/home/user/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and replace the contents of the file with the contents of `key.pub`
4. Try `ssh` into the machine with the new private key
5. If you can `ssh` with the new key, reboot the machine so that all active ssh sessions are closed
6. If you cannot `ssh` with the new key, go back to step 2 and see what went wrong.